# Escaping a String for Use in a preg_ Regular Expression

Tags: php, regex, escaping, pcre

Is there a canonical function/method for escaping a string to be used in a `preg_`, such that any special PCRE characters will be interpreted as literal.  Basically, a know way to ensure that something like

```
I am a fancy string (well, that guy ... said I was fancy)
```

is transformed into

```
I am a fancy string \(well, that guy \.\.\. said I was fancy\)
```

The use case is something like

```
$re = get_string_from_somewhere();
$re = our_magic_function($re);
preg_match_all('%'.$re.'%',$string, $matches);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that [preg_quote()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) is the answer you're looking for...

If you're using a custom delimiter (as you do in your example), be sure to set the second parameter ($delimiter) to the one used in the regex...  So your call would be `preg_quote($string, '%');`

Comment: No idea how i missed that on the php.net site.